# How to handle errors with onError in react useQuery, with variables

Tags: error-handling, react-hooks, state, apollo-client

Due to the reRender limits in React, I've gone with this solution when using useQuery, but I'm unsure if this is correct, as the 2nd useQuery is displaying the Modal, but the first 'useQuery' does not display the modal.

Note: If I use this,

```
if (queryColumns.error ) {
    handleErrorDialogOpen(t("Columns Groovy  baby Yeah"));
};
```

the app crashes, with too many re-renders.

The 2 useQueries in question:

```
    const queryColumns = useQuery(web_list_query, {
        variables: {entity: "device", variant: 'std'},
        onError: () => {
            handleErrorDialogOpen(t("There was an error retrieving rows data from 'web_list_query: device'"));
        },
        onCompleted: ()=> {
            handleErrorDialogOpen(t("Columns Groovy  baby Yeah"));
    }
});


const queryRows = useQuery(getDevices_query, {
    onError: () => {
        handleErrorDialogOpen(t("There was an error retrieving rows data from 'getDevices_query: device'"));
    },
    onCompleted: ()=> {
        handleErrorDialogOpen(t("Groovy  baby "));
    }
});
```

Comment: The useQuery setup looks fine. It's handleErrorDialogOpen() that's likely to cause a situation where 2nd useQuery is displaying the Modal, but the first 'useQuery' does not display the modal. Odds are, sometimes the opposite will happen if queryColumns returns first.

What does `handleErrorDialogOpen()` look like?